# Dúvida em autenticação/autorização baseada em perfís de acesso com WebAPI Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, permissões, asp.net-core-web-api, authorization

Tenho aqui uma aplicação Windows Forms + Sybase que possui um esquema de autenticação baseado em perfis de acesso. O diagrama do banco de dados é o seguinte:

[image: Diagrama de relacionamentos]

Na tabela **Permissão** temos as descrições de todas as funcionalidades do sistema. Se pode acessar o cadastro de clientes, se pode ajustar o estoque, se pode excluir um produto, se pode realizar uma venda, etc.

Na tabela **Perfil** temos "Gerente", "Vendedor 1", "Vendedor 2", "Administrador", etc.

E a tabela **Perfil_Permissao** é a entidade associativa das duas tabelas, onde dizemos quais funções cada perfil tem acesso.

E cada usuário tem seu perfil, com as devidas permissões de acesso do perfil.

Estou criando uma WebAPI para esse sistema, mas não estou conseguindo conciliar essa forma de autenticação do sistema atual com as possibilidades de autenticação do Asp.Net MVC.

Gostaria que os authorizes dos controllers e actions se baseassem nesse esquema de permissão para conceder ou não acesso a eles.

Existe alguma forma de adequar esse esquema de permissão de acesso do sistema atual aos "authorize", "policy", "claims", etc, do Asp.Net Core MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse formato de permissão por perfil, utilizei as claims para resolver o problema.
É possivel mandar, por exemplo, multiplas claims do tipo "Role", colocando cada uma das permissões nessas claims.

Pode ser usado algo similar a isso:

```
foreach(Permissao permissao in permissoes)
{
    Claim item = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, permissao.Codigo );
    lstClaims.Add(item);
}
```

E posteriormente a lista de claims é passada para o token utilizado.

```
...
Subject = new ClaimsIdentity( lstClaims.ToArray() )
...
```

Foi assim que resolvi.